# Regular Expression Repitition groups

Tags: regex

I have a Regex :

```
\*777\*[0-9]{10,}\*\d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100)\*\d+#
```

That is what i have these far.

It could handle input : *777*9283928839*89*5*9090#.

The format goes like this : `*777*phone*Qty*Item Code*pin#`

The problem is sometime the input will go like this :

```
*777*phone*Qty*Item Code*Qty*Item Code*Qty*Item Code*pin#
```

It will repeat at Qty*Item Code. But the Item code should be one of these 5,10,20,25,50,100

I confuse in making the regex check for Qty*Item Code.

Can someone give a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: If qty and item code can change, you can use `\*777\*[0-9]{10,}(?:\*\d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100))+\*\d+#`, if it has to be the same you could go by `\*777\*[0-9]{10,}(\*\d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100))\1*\*\d+#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\*777\*[0-9]{10,}\*(\d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100)\*)+\d+#
```

### Explanation

The part that's repeating seems to be this:

```
 \d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100)\*
```

If you enclose that in parentheses and add `+` after it, it will tell regex to match what's inside the parentheses one or more times:

```
(\d+\*(5|10|20|25|50|100)\*)+
```